# Load external resources in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, resources, .net-assembly

We got a project called "Main". In this project, all our resources are in a folder called Ress. When we call those resources we are using a Translator class that we made.

```
public class Translator
{
    ResourceManager m_ressourceManager;
    string m_completeRessourceName;
    public Translator(string ressourceName)
    {
        m_completeRessourceName = String.Format("Main.Ressources.{0}", ressourceName);
        m_ressourceManager = new ResourceManager(m_completeRessourceName, Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
    }

    public string GetString(string name)
    {
        string retString = "";
        try
        {
            retString = m_ressourceManager.GetString(name);
        }
        catch
        {
            retString = m_completeRessourceName + "." + name;
        }
    return retString;
    }
}
```

Everything is loading correctly in that project. Now we got a second project called "Home". In that project I added as link the traduction class. As you can see, our translator constructor is build to load resources in the "Main" project, subfolder "Ressources". For my about.aspx page in "Home" project, I created a resource file inside the Main/Ressources called About.en-CA.resx". When executing the code, I get no errors but the resource is not loaded. Both project has been rebuilded.

```
protected override void setPageTranslator()
{
    base.setPageTranslator();
    m_pageTranslator = new Translator("About");
}

protected override void LoadStrings()
{
    m_aboutTitle.Text = m_pageTranslator.GetString("AboutTitle");
}
```

Comment: Have tried using the current translator's assembly (typeof(Translator).Assembly) instead of Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()?

Comment: The result is the same :(